# Can ES6 object shorthand notation be combined with regular object notation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With ES6 we can now utilize object shorthand notation for creating objects...

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
var obj = { a, b, c };
```

Is it possible to combine shorthand notation with regular notation?

In other words, is the following legit?

```
var obj = {a, b, c, d: 'foo'};
```

And if so, are there any gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: What was result when you tried ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine shorthand notation with regular notation?

Yes. A property definition can be any of the following:

```
PropertyDefinition :
    IdentifierReference
    CoverInitializedName
    PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
    MethodDefinition
```

Source: [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer)

> And if so, are there any gotchas I should be aware of?

Nope.

Answer (score 1):

**According to Babel yes**

[See transpiled code results](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=var%20a%20%3D%201%2C%20b%20%3D%202%2C%20c%20%3D%203%3B%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20%7Ba%2C%20b%2C%20c%2C%20d%3A%20'foo'%7D%3B)

**Babel** translates this

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
var obj = {a, b, c, d: 'foo'};
```

into this in **es5**

```
var a = 1,
b = 2,
c = 3;

var obj = { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: 'foo' };
```

Also found a [github repo](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) by Luke Hoban that shows mixed objects being created